# SimpleDateFormat working in IST timezone but not in JST timezone

Tags: java, date, timezone, date-format, simpledateformat

I am parsing the date in format:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
```

When I do,

```
String collectDate = "Sun Nov 24 13:00:07 IST 2013";
Date date = formatter.parse(collectDate);
```

the string is successfully parsed.

But this does not work when the same code is run in JST timezone machine with date as "`Sun Nov 24 13:00:07 JST 2013`".

Need help regarding this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does "does not work" mean?  Exception?  Crash?  Hang?  Wrong results?

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm. is that India Standard Time? Israel Standard Time? Irish Standard Time?  All are valid interpretations of IST. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations) and [here](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/).

If I can't tell, how do you expect the computer to know?

The only abbreviations that are going to be guaranteed are those defined by [RFC822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt), which are EST, CST, MST, PST, EDT, CDT, MDT, PDT, GMT, UT.  Even then, you should avoid using them.  CST is has 5 different interpretations other than the American Central Standard Time that is defined in RFC822.

Instead, you should be using IANA time zone identifiers, such as `Asia/Kolkata` or `Asia/Tokyo`.

Answer (score 0):

Java uses UTC (nee GMT) internally. When you display it, you're getting that moment in time (but with the local offset from `GMT+9` e.g. `Japan Standard Time`).

Answer (score 0):

The javadoc clearly states that

> SimpleDateFormat is a concrete class for formatting and parsing dates in a locale-sensitive manner.

and that's what it does exactly, its used only for parsing and formatting the Date objects. Implicitly java uses UTC time to represent the date object. If you try to print it, it uses the local timezone set in the system to 'Format' the date object and print it to the standard output.

You can follow the same while processing dates in JST format. Here's the snippet of code that does that.

```
public static void main( String[] args )
   {

  SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");


  String collectDate = "Sun Nov 24 13:00:07 JST 2013";
  try
  {
     Date date = formatter.parse(collectDate);
     System.out.println(date);
     formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("JST"));
     System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
  }
  catch (ParseException e)
  {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }

   }
```

You can clearly see the difference between first and the second sysout.